# Bind one click in jQuery mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click it is bind **more than 5 click** action.

> This jQuery block are in mouseenter jquery function.

It bind more than on click.

Below is whole function.

```
 $('.parent').mouseover(function () {
    $('#elem').show();
    $('#elem').on('click', function (event) {
        alert('edit');
    });

    $(this).mouseleave(function () {
        $('#elem').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Your question is bit unclear to me, Do you want to `unbind` click event when you `click` once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had make solution from

> Dekel answer

**I changed this code:**

```
 $('.parent').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#elem').show();
    $('#elem').on('click', function (event) {
        alert('edit');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#elem').unbind( "click" );
        }, 100);
    });

    $(this).mouseleave(function () {
        $('#elem').hide();
    });
});
```

**To this one:** Where I bind one click per mouseenter and still can show or hide buttons

```
 $('.parent').one('mouseenter', function () {
    $('#elem').click(function (event) {
        alert('edit');
    });
}); 

 $('.parent').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#elem').show();

    $(this).mouseleave(function () {
        $('#elem').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please accept my answer if it gave you the correct solution :) (a voteup will also be appreciated. Thanks!)

Comment: I had voted up, your answer was helpful for finding solution. But real problem solution that can help to other member I had wrote below.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that every time you put your mouse over the `.parent` element - you attach a new `click` event listener to the `#elem` element. If you hover that element several times (and you don't click), the `click` event is already attached and therefor you will get several "alerts".
Another thing to note is that with `mouseover` - every time you "switch" between elements that are one-inside-another (like your example) - that event is fire.

```js
$('.parent').mouseover(function () {
  console.log('mouseover fired for .parent');
    $('#elem').show();
    $('#elem').on('click', function (event) {
        console.log('#elem clicked');
    });

    $(this).mouseleave(function () {
        $('#elem').hide();
    });
});

$('.parent1').click('#elem1', function(event) {
  console.log('#elem1 clicked');
});

$('.parent1').mouseover(function () {
  $('#elem1').show();
});

$('.parent1').mouseleave(function () {
  $('#elem1').hide();
});
```

```css
.parent, .parent1 { border: 1px solid red; width: 50px; height: 50px; margin: 25px; padding: 25px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div id="elem">
    123
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent1">
  <div id="elem1">
    123
  </div>
</div>
```